# KineticJS - Make stroke invisible/remove stroke

Tags: kineticjs

I have some text set up with a border as follows:

```
var line1 = new Kinetic.Text({
     x: 190,
     y: 40,
     text: "Line 1",            
     stroke: "black",
     strokeWidth: 1,
     padding: 5
}
```

But I want to set-up an event that removes the border. How do I do this? setStroke("none") doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting stroke to *null*, rather than "none", works for this, as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/FCuk5/6/

```
line1.setStroke(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

```
line1.setStroke(''); // or setStroke('rgba(0,0,0,0)');

line1.setStrokeWidth(0);
```

Either way, you have to redraw the layer afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Found I had to use this to stop a black line from appearing the width of the stroke when the line was on top of other shapes:

```
line1.setStroke('rgba(0,0,0,0)');
```